# tizen emulator not connecting to device

Tags: android, tizen, tizen-wearable-sdk, tizen-web-app, tizen-emulator

Hi I am trying to connect the Tizen Emulator version : 2.3.0 Rev2 to an android device.

I downloaded the files for apk files from [here](http://developer.samsung.com/technical-doc/view.do?v=T000000162). I have done the port forwarding like shown below before starting the emulator :

```
adb -d forward tcp:8230 tcp:8230
```

But even after starting the Emaulator still the HostManagerForEmul shows status as disconnected.

I was following the complete instructions from the youtube video found [here](https://youtu.be/SFz3n49QUCs?t=22s).

Answer (score 1):

A couple things to try...

1. If Gear Manager is installed on the Android handset, uninstall it. Gear Manager is not compatible with HostManagerForEmul.
2. Restart sap-server from the emulator.

Comment: I tried the sap-server restart from the emulator but it did not work. Says its not found. I will try the gear manager uninstall. Also does the pc running the tizen emulator and the phone running the HostManagerForEmul have to be in the same.wifi network ?.

Comment: I tried the command;

[ $> killall sap-server ]

But I get the output

[ sap-server: no process found ]

Comment: Yes, same network. Otherwise the packets will not route.

Comment: Yup they are on the same network but still not luck. Any idea why the command [killall sap-server]  is returning [no-process] ?.

Comment: I am getting the same error, no process found, could you get to the solution? if so please explain..

Comment: I'm getting the same error too. Any solutions for this? And I'm not able to found if I'm missing any step

Comment: I got the same error too (no-process found). Any updates??

Answer (score 0):

I have same problem, after struggling I have finally connected
Here is solution , Go to package manager install both highlighted from extension SDK as shown in picture

[image: Package Manager]

after installing connect android phone install apk provided in tutorial and run

`adb -d forward tcp:8230 tcp:8230`

Now delete emulator and make again, after reboot it will install extension tools and on first boot it will show like this
[image: Gear]

After that it will reboot again automatically , and on Android side it will show Connected. Done :)